# Creating an EXE from Python Script, how to bundle other exes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, exe, pyinstaller

I am creating an EXE file from a python script using pyinstaller and I need to include the Selenium Chrome and IE executables with this exe. How can I bundle those so when someone installs my exe it also includes both of those?